# How to empty and reuse a list to save values in a particular cell of dataframe's column?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am doing web scrapping where with the help of Python Reddit API Wrapper (PRAW) to extract the title of post, total number of comments (int) and all comments. Now, to store the values row by row, I'm using df.loc[] of dataframe that contains three columns i.e. 'Title', 'Number of comments' and 'Comments'. So, to put all the comments in a single cell/row, I'm using a list. Now, I want to empty this list and reuse it in order to store all comments when new post is taken.

The corresponding code:

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Number of comments', 'Comments'])



reddit_read_only = praw.Reddit(client_id = os.environ.get("client_id"),
                                client_secret = os.environ.get("client_secret"),
                                user_agent = os.environ.get("user_agent"))

def web_scrap_reddit(name, value):

    i = 1
    subreddit = reddit_read_only.subreddit(name)
    while i <= value:
        lst = []
        for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=value):
            if submission.num_comments != 0:
                for comment in submission.comments.list():
                    lst.append(comment.body) 
                df.loc[i] = [submission.title, submission.num_comments, lst]

            elif submission.num_comments == 0:
                df.loc[i] = [submission.title, submission.num_comments, ['No comments']]
            i += 1
    print(df.head())
    # df.to_csv('Reddit_web_scrap1.csv', index=False)

web_scrap_reddit('Python', 3)
```

Here, as you can see that first I created a dataframe with three columns. Now, I created a function web_scrap_reddit() that will store all the extracted values and create a dataframe. So, whenever in a post there are no comments or comments is zero, than at that particular cell, 'No comments' will be stored.

Output of the code:

```
                                               Title  Number of comments                                           Comments
1  Sunday Daily Thread: What's everyone working o...                   8  [First few chapters of “Python Crash Course” b...
2           Tuesday Daily Thread: Advanced questions                   0                                      [No comments]
3  Python Tutorial: Simulate the Powerball Lotter...                  14  [First few chapters of “Python Crash Course” b...

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

As you can see, it works for first two post as one post has no comments and one post has 8 comments. But when a post with comments occur, in the comments column, I get the same comments as post 1 contains, whereas as the post with 14 comments have different comments and I want to store those particular comments in new row/loc of dataframe. I dont' know how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should change where you reset list,
i also suggest you to start i with 0,

```
for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=value):
    lst = []
    if submission.num_comments != 0:
```